# How to get the cached music file in firefox?

Tags: firefox, proc

A mp3 musci played.

```
lsof  |grep  mp3
firefox-e 9450         debian8  mem       REG                8,3    285392    1857732 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0

ls  /proc/9450/
attr       clear_refs       cpuset   fd       limits     mem         net        oom_score      projid_map  setgroups  statm    timers
autogroup  cmdline          cwd      fdinfo   loginuid   mountinfo   ns         oom_score_adj  root        smaps      status   uid_map
auxv       comm             environ  gid_map  map_files  mounts      numa_maps  pagemap        sched       stack      syscall  wchan
cgroup     coredump_filter  exe      io       maps       mountstats  oom_adj    personality    sessionid   stat       task

cat  /proc/9450/mem  > /tmp/test.mp3
cat: /proc/9450/mem: Input/output error
```

How to get the music played?

Comment: Seems you try to access the memory of your libmp3lame shared library (used by firefox) - that is executable code, variables of the lib and *maybe* portions of your mp3- file, but you won't be able to get the mp3 directly out this way.

Comment: How to get it then ?

Comment: If I could just tell you. Sometimes processes use temporary files that - even if deleted on the Filesystem - are available using the file- handles (fd) - for them your'e perfectly right with lsof. Those can be copied and opened as you tried to. But if a file is  scattered around in process memory there is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

To replay the music in firefox,at the same time to execute the code.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k ouput.mp3
```